# .Net Core: what is the best version to use? SDK 2.1.301 or Runtime 2.1.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core

what is the best one to work in .net core? SDK 2.1.301 or Runtime 2.1.1?

I am trying to create a webapi with dotnet, I run dotnet and set http://localhost:5000/api/values/get?Id=1 and fails telling me page not found

I don't know if it is the version of dotnet I installed, I used SDK.

Comment: You can't *build* anything with just the runtime. The SDK includes the runtime. If you get an error it's because the URL is wrong. It should be `http://localhost:5000/api/values/1`

Comment: If you get an error with Postman, it's because Postman blocks the self-signed certificate created by the Web API template. The call will work once you disable `SSL certificate verification` in `Settings > General`, if you use a trusted certificate instead, or if you trust the self-signed certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is wrong. It should be `http://localhost:5000/api/values/1`. That's specified in the controller method itself with a routing attribute :

The SDK *inlcudes* the runtime so there's no reason to worry about order of installation.

The SDK contains the tools and libraries needed to create and build a project, like `dotnet new` and `dotnet build`. It runs on top of the runtime, it doesn't provide its own.

```
    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
```

This means that the `Get` action will be called in response to the `GET` verb and the `id` parameter will be retrieved from the URL itself.

The runtime contains only the parts that *run* a program.

**UPDATE**

The URL just works with the default Web API template. To verify :

1. Create a new folder
2. Run `dotnet new webapi` to create a new Web API project
3. Run `dotnet build` to build it and then `dotnet run`
4. Paste `http://localhost:5000/api/values/1` in any browser.

The response will be

```
value
```

**UPDATE 2**

Postman also works, once `SSL certificate verification` in `Settings > General` is disabled.

The Web API template comes with HTTPS preconfigured and works with a self-signed certificate. Calls to `http://localhost:5000` will be redirected to `https://localhost:5001`.

Comment: it is build for the same Postman  but anyway I tested your way before error and it is the same problem. without parameters, I have Get() function same problem

Comment: @David no it's not. If you create a new project, run it and simply paste `http://localhost:5000/api/values/1` in the URL you'll get back `value`. You *don't* need to specify the action name in the URL. If you have issues with the URL it's because you modified the code. In any case, post your code. There's nothing wrong with the SDK

Comment: @David if it works on the browser, it works. How are you making the call with Postman? If there's any issue it's there. What did you try and what was the problem? Perhaps Postman doesn't handle automatic redirection to `https` ? The Web API template comes with HTTPS preconfigured.

Comment: I only changed SSL certificate verification to disabled as you said in the answer. It was activated.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the framework, there is no difference if you use SDK or runtime. The first one is designed for development, while the latter one for production environments.

Issue comes out from your project, routing for e.g., but difficult to say once you need to share more details. Mentioned framework variants are irrelevant here.